# How does a stove crack like this? What does it take to make this happen?

Tags: repair, appliances, stove, crack

Is this normal? Stove makes explode-like sound and cracks. Can this be fixed or do we need to replace it?[image]

Comment: Not normal.  Imagine one of three things, a defect, someone dropped a heavy pot/pan and weaken it, or rapid temperature change(red hot to ice cold).

Comment: That does seem quite unusual. I wouldn't think it can be fixed, but that you'd have to replace it. You'd probably have to replace the whole cook top, as those appear to be one-piece units. [Edit] your post to include the brand and model - someone may have more info for you.

Comment: Why I dislike *fancy* glass-top stoves and prefer *old-fashioned* metal ones. Well, that and you can replace one burner on an old-stye rather than the whole top - in 30 seconds or so.

Comment: If you don't drop heavy pots on it (which I imagine most people don't do :) ) it'll save you a lot of time cleaning. We went from a glass top induction unit in the previous house to an old fashioned gas stove, and the extensive cleaning required with more spattery types of cooking is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a normal occurrence for this type of cooktop. It usually happens when some thing heavy is dropped on the glass, cracking it and then bringing it up to heat. The glass can be replaced by purchasing it from an appliance parts store and doing it yourself or having an appliance repair store change it for you. If you pay to have it done, it will probably cost more than just replacing the entire cooktop because it's a time consuming job.